# How come spring boot application breaks when adding wlfullclient-12.1.1 external jar?

Tags: java, spring, jar, spring-boot

When I add wlfullclient-12.1.1 external jar into my external jar libraries my spring application breaks. When I remove the jar it works fine. How can I incorporate the jars without receiving an error?
[many errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLy9j.png)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the exception you're getting... Also not clear how do you add jars(pom.xml/build.gradle or some other way)

Comment: I'm adding the jars by right clicking the project and configure path. I'll upload the error that I received

Answer (score 0):

It's embedding a different version of javax.validation, and there's a missing method that Spring, via Hibernate Validation, is trying to invoke.

Comment: How can I modify the javax.validation verison that will match the weblogic jar?

Comment: The jar is incompatible with other stuff you're using, welcome to dealing with weblogic (a pain I know all to well).  Is there a "non-full" version of the client you can use instead?  Or perhaps use a dependency management tool like maven or ivy?

Comment: If I use maven depedency management do I just simply add a the plugin?

Comment: If I add the maven dependecy. It would not pick up weblogic.health and few other variables that were defined.

Comment: Can those be set as environment variables?

Comment: They are imports. Import.weblogic.health,